# JS prototype class with private methods not accessing properties

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to JS and especially to prototypes.
I have this class and I cannot figure out how to access the properties.

```
var Lobby = function (preloader, serverConn) {
  // Hold a reference to EventBus
  this.serverConn = serverConn;
  this.preloader = preloader;

  this.scheduleItemService = new ScheduledItemService(this.preloader);
  this.stage = new createjs.Stage("lobbyCanvas");
};

Lobby.prototype.start = function(me, signedRequest) {
    sendMessage(data, function() {
       // inside this scope this.stage is undefined!
       renderLobbyImages(this.stage, this.scheduleItemService);
    });
};

function renderLobbyImages(stage, scheduleItemService) {
  stage.update();
};
```

Calling code:

```
var lobby = new Lobby(preloader, serverConn);
lobby.start(me, status.authResponse.signedRequest);
```

What am I doing wrong accessing 'renderLobbyImages' ??

Thank you :-)

Comment: Are you getting any errors..? What is wrong..?

Comment: How are you calling `start()`?

Comment: Please show us how you're using the constructor, and how you're calling `.start`.

Comment: You had working code and no problem description initially (which means there was no problem) and then you updated the question with non-working code... @__@

Comment: I added how I run this code.

Comment: I edit the code to reflect what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Put `console.log(this)` in `start`, what does it show?

Comment: Look at my latest edit - it shows better my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, `this` is not resolved based on where it is declared/used. It is resolved when it gets called. (see: [How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628?s=1|3.9123#13441628)).

Therefore, in the code above, since `this` is called in the callback to `sendMessage()`, and since `sendMessage` is asynchronous (meaning the callback will be called long after the call to `start()` have returned), `this` is therefore referring to the global object (which is `window` in web browsers, something unnamed in node.js).

So effectively, your code is doing this (no pun intended):

```
sendMessage(data, function() {
   renderLobbyImages(stage, scheduleItemService);
});
```

Since there are no global variables called `stage` or `scheduleItemService` both are effectively undefined!

Fortunately, there is a workaround for this. You can capture the correct object in a closure:

```
var foo = this;
sendMessage(data, function() {
   renderLobbyImages(foo.stage, foo.scheduleItemService);
});
```

Alternatively, you can pass the correct object (`this`) into an IIFE:

```
(function(x){
    sendMessage(data, function() {
        renderLobbyImages(x.stage, x.scheduleItemService);
    });
})(this); // <-------- this is how we pass this
```

or:

```
sendMessage(data, (function(a){
    return function(){
        renderLobbyImages(a.stage, a.scheduleItemService);
    }
})(this));
```

Or in this case, since `stage` and `scheduleItemService` are not functions, you can even pass them directly:

```
sendMessage(data, (function(a,b){
    return function(){
        renderLobbyImages(a,b);
    }
})(this.stage, this.scheduleItemService));
```

There are lots of solutions to this problem. Just use the one you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks a lot - You certainly nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

1. `this` is missing in your constructor function on `scheduleItemService`.
2. Some functions you call to assign values seem to be not returning anything.

   ```
    new createjs.Stage("lobbyCanvas");
    new ScheduledItemService
   ```

Your calling method is alright.

`this` always refers to the calling object. When you say...

```
varlobby = new Lobby();
lobby.start();
```

... your calling object is `lobby` which has all the fields the `start()` function needs. But there initialization seems to be not working properly.

Please read this [MDN starter guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Also we are having a some discussion about classical and prototype based OOP in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359424/how-to-implement-classical-class-inheritance-through-prototypes) question. Please see the [answer of Paul S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34360607/4185234) for more about the tutorial I mentioned. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34420032/4185234) if you need to see the tutorial in classical OOP light.

Comment: Your constructor function is ok. And you are calling it correctly. The only possibility is that `createjs.Stage` and `ScheduledItemService` don't create the properties as expected. So, they are 'undefined'. Please set a breakpoint there and see in the console if these functions work properly.

Comment: I know what's the problem but I don't know how to solve it. if I call the method directly from the .start() method than everything is defined. *BUT* if I call the method within an inner function of the 'sendMessage' method - then it is undefined!